# Is unreferenced blob automatically collected by GC in firebird?

Tags: c, database, firebird

By unreferenced I mean it's not inserted to a table as a column in a row. So after calling `isc_create_blob2` to create a blob I don't insert the `blobId` to a table. Instead I simply call `isc_close_blob` to close the handle.

If the answer is yes then what would happen if I don't even call `isc_close_blob`? The api guide says you should call `isc_cancel_blob` in this case or the storage space allocated for the blob will remain in the database but it doesn't explicitly clarify whether it's just temporarily kept in the database until the program that called `isc_create_blob2` exits and will be collected by then or it's really stuck in the database forever.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't close or cancel the blob, it will be cancelled when your connection is closed (maybe even when the transaction gets committed or rolled back), and the blob will (eventually) get garbage collected. I can't find an authorative source for that though (although [this page](http://ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/general/doc_54) mentions that blobs not (yet) associated with a column are marked as temporary). You might want to consider asking on the firebird-support mailinglist as well.